# MAAS cannot get power state for server with AMT. Cannot power on after it is powered off

Tags: networking, server, maas, openstack

I am putting an OpenStack cloud in our lab for evaluation purposes. To do so I installed latest stable MAAS (1.9.4+bzr4592-0ubuntu1 (trusty1)) on Ubuntu 14.04.5. For this openstack ubuntu based cloud I am using 7 Dell VPro boxes with AMT (9020 i7-quad cores with 32GB RAM and 2 SSDs each).

- All of them have latest BIOS updates from Dell and are set up for Wake-on-lan, boot on on-board NIC-PXE only.
- MAAS server has two nics as well as required. **em1** (on board NIC) is connected to the internal router connected to the MAAS box only. em1 has static IP of 10.10.0.1,
- MAAS server's second NIC **p1p1** interface is connected to the internal F/W with static IP of 10.71.101.1. This NIC has internet access.
- Servers have two NICs (one on board and another PCI-e Intel NIC). When I enlist them, I take out the second NIC connection and keep the on-board NIC connected only.
- After installing the MAAS, I boot up the servers one by one. They all appear on MAAS Nodes dashboard. I do NOT see the power sign (usual) and they are not powered OFF after getting the "new" state.
- When I want to set their AMT properties and try to power them off, I get a warning that I need to install amtterm and wsmancli. So I install (also installed ether_wake) and reboot.
- After that I can power off the boxes **via MAAS**. **But, the power state still shows green (on) on the maas dashboard** while the boxes are physically powered off.
- I try to check the power state for the servers, it fails. MAAS shows red (power failure) on the dashboard. But I am not sure why? Funny thing is, I manually turn the power on and then off, while clicking on the "check now" button, then the power icon turns gray as expected.
- I can ping the boxes (when they are powered on) using their IPs (10.10.1.31) from the MAAS box.

Ubuntu 14.04 is used as the default OS for bootstrapping. I have the latest updates as of yesterday.

Couldn't get into the servers to capture the cloud init logs. Tried the workaround posted on ubuntu site, no avail.

I have seen some AMT > 8 issues on the web, though, I doubt those would resurface? In any case, 3 of my boxes use Intel MEBx v8.0.0.0072/**Intel ME v8.1.65.1586** while other four are Intel MEBx v9.0.0.0029/**Intel ME v9.1.37.1002**.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my **/etc/network/interfaces** on my maas server:

```
# The primary INTERNET (via OPT1) facing network interface. USB dongle.
auto p1p1
iface p1p1 inet static
        address 10.71.101.1
        netmask 255.255.0.0
        network 10.71.0.0
        broadcast 10.71.255.255
        gateway 10.71.0.1
        dns-nameservers 10.10.0.1 10.71.0.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

# The private/MAAS facing network interface. Onboard NIC.
auto em1
iface em1 inet static
        address 10.10.0.1
        netmask 255.255.0.0
```